How to handle conflicts when merging one shared branch into another
I have come across a problem with our merging process in GIT and hope somebody can help me resolve it.
Full disclaimer: I know little to nothing about GIT so apologies in advance.
Long story short we currently have a DEVELOP branch that is protected so nobody can push directly to the branch. When developing we create a FEATURE branch, raise a PR and complete that PR into DEVELOP.
When then have a RELEASE branches (created off DEVELOP) that when complete are merged both back into DEVELOP and then our MASTER branch.
The problem we have is that our recent release process was horrendous and a number of fixes were applied direct to MASTER in a panic.
To ensure these fixes were in DEVELOP we created a feature branch off DEVELOP, merged MASTER into the FEATURE then completed the feature into DEVELOP.
As a double check our developers wanted to merge MASTER into DEVELOP locally to check everything was ok. The problem here is that all the code that was fixed in the feature is still showing up as conflicted in this merge.
I "assume" this is because when merging, GIT is looking at the master commits and not seeing them in the DEVELOP branch - they don't appear to get transferred as part of the feature we completed.
The question I have is, Is this a problem? Should I always be able to merge from MASTER to DEVELOP and see no issues OR do I need to somehow tell DEVELOP that the last X commits to MASTER are already in there?
One of our developers has suggested temporarily removing the develop protection, merging, fixing and then turning it back on but this seems dangerous.
Any help/advice/experience anybody could offer to this noob would be greatly appreciated.

FYI, I changed the title, and removed some of the tags, and added the git-flow tag since that is the name of the branching strategy that you're using.

Just resolve the conflicts and finish the merge. No problem.

If the question is "why does this happen", that's pretty obvious if you know what a merge is. Read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

I just linked to @matt's tutorial on merges, which fit perfectly into my answer. I'd recommend reading through that either before or after my answer. (Or at least the part titled "When Git needs help".)

tl;dr: It appears that conceptually you are doing everything correctly. Furthermore, it's perfectly normal to have conflicts in your situation. Conflicts are simply a possible side effect of simultaneous development on two different paths.
The long answer:
In Git-Flow, there are 4 different types of shared branches that need to be merged at some point, and sometimes this is challenging when you have conflicts with one of those merges. Here's another answer related to conflicts in Git-Flow, and an excerpt from that answer1 explains:

With standard Git Flow, the only time you should ever potentially have conflicts are when merging:

main back into release (hotfix conflicts with release)
main back into develop (release/hotfix conflicts with develop)
release back into develop (release conflicts with develop)


(Note in the above excerpt main and master are synonymous.)
Merging master into develop is a possible merge that can have conflicts, and in your case it's because the changes on master were due to hotfixes that conflict with other changes already on develop. This is perfectly normal. As for how to handle them, it turns out that the way you resolve the conflicts in this situation is no different than how you resolve conflicts in any other situation, and the way you merge one shared branch into another is (usually) the same regardless of whether you have conflicts!
For example, let's suppose you wish to merge master into develop. If you were to do this locally, you would do something like this:
git fetch
git branch -D develop # delete a possible old local version of develop
git switch develop # checkout develop
git merge origin/master # merge in the latest master
# Resolve any conflicts you might have (using other devs to help if needed)
# if you had conflicts, stage and commit

git push # this will fail if you have branch protection on develop

In one of my repos that uses Git-Flow, we have the Git-Flow merges automated, so that we can just press a button to perform the merges of one shared branch into another. The user that performs those merges has special permission to bypass branch protection so it can push without a PR. No humans have the bypass permission, by default.
The only reason the automated merge can fail, is when there are conflicts. In that case one of us will do the above steps exactly, and just before the push, we do as you suggested: we have an admin give that user the ability to push without a PR. They push, then the admin immediately removes that permission from that user.
Sometimes that push still fails though. This happens when someone else completed a PR into develop during the time that person was working to resolve the conflicts locally, which takes some non-negligible amount of time, between the fetch and the push. when this happens, you basically have 2 options:

You can throw the current version of develop away and repeat the above steps with the hopes that you'll be faster the next time around. (You could even temporarily lock develop so that you could make sure it doesn't happen a second time, but I don't always recommend this.2)
Do the other thing you are currently doing, which is to create a temporary feature branch and making a new PR with that. For example:

# ...continuing from above
git push # fails because the tip of your branch is no longer up to date

# create a new temp branch
# (remember local develop has the merge commit with the resolved conflicts)
git switch -c merge-master-into-develop develop
git push

# now go create a PR from merge-master-into-develop into develop
# Be happy there are no conflicts anymore

So, to summarize, what you've been doing, and what was proposed, are both good ideas for how to handle merge conflicts on protected shared branches. I think at this point you simply need to get some practice resolving merge conflicts, and understanding the scenarios which create them, which will come naturally with time as you work to resolve them.

1 In the case of merging main (or master) into develop, this is assuming that you are dong this right after merging either release or hotfix into main. Strict Git Flow suggests merging release or hotfix into both main and develop, but there are some minor advantages to merging into main first, and then merging main into develop. This is touched upon at the end of the linked answer to the other question, and nowadays is a fairly popular tweak to strict Git Flow.
2 The reason I don't recommend locking branches in general, is because it can mess up automated processes that try to write to a branch. For example, automated builds that write a build commit could fail, and (in AzDO at least) any PR that is set to auto-complete, if it passes all tests and tries to complete the PR while the branch is locked, it will fail and turn off auto-completion, meaning it won't ever complete until someone notices this happened and completes the PR manually.
